# SDL_WINDOWEVENT missing

Tags: c++, sdl

I am using the latest version of SDL, the enum SDL_WINDOWEVENT seems to be missing

inside SDL_Events.h, the definition of SDL_Events is:

```
/** General event structure */
typedef union SDL_Event {
    Uint8 type;
    SDL_ActiveEvent active;
    SDL_KeyboardEvent key;
    SDL_MouseMotionEvent motion;
    SDL_MouseButtonEvent button;
    SDL_JoyAxisEvent jaxis;
    SDL_JoyBallEvent jball;
    SDL_JoyHatEvent jhat;
    SDL_JoyButtonEvent jbutton;
    SDL_ResizeEvent resize;
    SDL_ExposeEvent expose;
    SDL_QuitEvent quit;
    SDL_UserEvent user;
    SDL_SysWMEvent syswm;
} SDL_Event;
```

I know there is a SDL_WINDOWEVENT from the wiki

http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_WindowEvent?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryStruct%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEvents%29%7C%28SGStructures%29

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Edit to clarify the Problem

If you look at the link provided, the sample code gives

```
void PrintEvent(const SDL_Event * event)
{
    if (event->type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {
        switch (event->window.event) {
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN:
            fprintf(stderr, "Window %d shown", event->window.windowID);
            break;
// snip
}
```

My Code

```
    SDL_Event sdlEvent = {0};

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent))
    {
        if(sdlEvent.type == SDL_QUIT)// || isTriggered(SDLK_ESCAPE))
            System::getEventManagerGlobal().broadcastEvent( Event("QUIT") );
        if(sdlEvent.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT)
        {
            if(sdlEvent.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MOVED)
            {
                // snip
            }
        }
    }
```

error C2065: 'SDL_WINDOWEVENT' : undeclared identifier
error C2039: 'window' : is not a member of 'SDL_Event'
sdl_events.h(227) : see declaration of 'SDL_Event'
error C2228: left of '.event' must have class/struct/union
error C2065: 'SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MOVED' : undeclared identifier

Comment: By 'missing', do you mean SDL is not compiling due to an undefined symbol `SDL_WINDOWEVENT`?

Comment: @ Xavier Ho, Exactly, my project is not compiling due to an undefined symbol SDL_WINDOWEVENT.

Comment: Maybe that event has been obsoleted? Or not implemented yet for SDL 2.0? It's not even in the union you posted in the question.

Comment: @aCuria: Care to paste your compiler error in you question?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg [Edited] Hm, you have a good point there. According to the docs, `SDL_WINDOWEVENT` is of type `Uint32`.  But the OP posted `SDL_Event`, while the doc is for `SDL_WindowEvent`.  What's even more confusing, the doc for `SDL_WindowEvent` (http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_Event) has `Uint32` for `type`, not `Uint8`.

Comment: Could you check your version of SDL? `sdl-config --version`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue I was having - Joachim and user1202136 clued me on

I was mistaken on the version of SDL I am using, which explains why the methods don't exist..